# How I can specify a separate file for my aliases in oh-my-zsh?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm preparing a bash script, that will set a bunch of handy shell aliases at once. I'm using a pair of **iTerm2** and **oh-my-zsh**.

I know that I can manually add aliases into `~/.zshrc`.
I also know that I can even to that automatically by calling `sed` with some extra stuff, but **for separation and consistency I would like to keep my "omz" aliases in a separate file** like `~/.bash_aliases`?

So then my bash script could easily override the content of that file and put a list of my aliases without worrying, that I will remove by accident some other settings from `~/.zshrc`.

How I could specify a separate file for aliases in oh-my-zsh?

Comment: Where you are inserting your aliases in `~/.zshrc`, replace them with `. ~/.zsh_aliases`, where you put the aliases instead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is to remove the alias definitions from `~/.zshrc` into the file `~/.zsh_aliases` and replace the multiple alias commands in `~/.zshrc` by:

```
. ~/.zsh_aliases
```

You can use the same technique for other sections of `~/.zshrc`: for instance, you may find it convenient to move any function definitions into `~/.zsh_functions`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i'm using oh-my-zsh and in the ~/.zshrc file i placed the linked file path as

```
source FILE_PATH
```

then restart the terminal and all done.